# how to create a value of a data type having empty constructor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, constructor

The PortNumber in `Network` package has no constructor at all, whose definition and doc as follows (or please refer to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/Network.html):

```
data PortNumber

Use the Num instance (i.e. use a literal) to create a PortNumber value with
the correct network-byte-ordering. You should not use the PortNum constructor.
It will be removed in the next release.

instances
...
Num PortNumber
...
```

What make me confused is how it can use a Num instance to create a `PortNumber`? I know that PortNumber is an instance of class Num and it can be considered as a `Num`, but how it can just see a Num instance (for example a literal `10000`) as a PortNumber ?
When constructing a PortID which has a constructor as `PortNumber PortNumber`, it seems ok to just use `PortNumber 10000`. How does this happen ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you look at the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/src/Network-Socket-Types.html#PortNumber) you see this:

```
newtype PortNumber = PortNum Word16 deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable)
```

right now.

And if you look at the documentation you will see this warning too:

> DEPRECATED PortNum "Do not use the PortNum constructor. Use the Num instance. PortNum will be removed in the next release."

What's meant here is that `PortNumber` is an [instance of `Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/src/Network-Socket-Types.html#PortNumber) and so you can use `fromInteger` - which Haskell does by default when it sees an integer numeral like `1`, `20`, ... - that is also why

```
Prelude> :t 666
666 :: Num a => a
```

So instead of using the *constructor* `PortNum 10000` you can just use `10000` and it will be an `PortNumber` automatically in the right context (see bellow)

---

For the `PortId` part: `PortNumber` there is a constructor for `PortId` ([see source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/src/Network.html#PortID):

```
data PortID =
      Service String
    | PortNumber PortNumber
    | UnixSocket String
```

) - so if you use `PortNumber 10000` you are indeed using the `Int -> PortNumber -> PortId` path right now as `10000` (using `fromInteger`) is converted into a `PortNumber` and is then plugged into the *constructor* `PortNumber` to get a `PortId`

---

aside from this you might see examples with *empty* data-definitions - but as Haskell is lazy you can often still use `undefined :: MyEmptyType` to get a *value* for a place that will not be evaluated anyway.

There is a nice example in [Fun with type functions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/fun-with-type-funs/typefun.pdf)
 using exactly this:

```
data Zero
data Succ n

class Nat n where
   toInt :: n -> Int

instance Nat Zero where
   toInt _ = 0

instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
   toInt _ = 1 + toInt (undefined :: n)
```

Comment: You could also mention the fact that `PortNumber` has a `Num` instance, which explains why numeric literals can be implicitly converted into a `PortNumber`.

Comment: yes I guess so - but I thought that was clear (hilu mentioned it in the question and it's in the *warning*) - let me see where I can put it

Comment: I believe the last example requires `EmptyDataDecls` extension enabled.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes - I think it's mentioned in the article - if not the compiler will tell you ;)